# Why was my suggested edit rejected and someone else's approved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

I made [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1132541) to a question which just improved formatting, and it was rejected by the "Community" user.

Right after me, the user RvdK made the same fixes, and then user Vinay [suggested another edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1132557) to the question, which got approved.

Why was my suggestion rejected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RvdK clicked "edit" before you posted your edit, and then submitted his after you submitted yours.

The system noticed this conflict, and because the other user has sufficient reputation to edit posts without review, his edit was chosen as the edit to keep.  Your edit was discarded.  The way in which it is discarded is for "Community" to reject the proposal.

Comment: I'm not sure the "substantial" thing applies to this case. I think a 2k user's or OP's edit always trumps a suggested edit. I can't find anything saying one way or the other though.

Comment: @animuson And yet neither was the case here.  The other edit wasn't from the OP, and wasn't from a 2k user, it was another suggested edit.

Comment: No it wasn't, it was from a 7.8k user - [see the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13727680/revisions). The other suggested edit occurred after that edit.

Comment: @animuson Ah, you're correct.

Answer (score 7):

When a suggested edit is rejected by Community, then it was automatically rejected because another edit conflicted with yours.

Two reviewers had already approved your edit, but it conflicted with the edit made by RvdK.

Tough luck!